# OU timestamp ComObject

Tags: c#, com, active-directory

Here is some sample code I have that finds all computer objects in an OU. When I print out the property fields, I get a `System.__ComObject` for several of the values such as `lastLogon`, `lastLogonTimestamp`, `pwdLastSet`, `uSNChanged`, etc. I assume these are all date-ish type values of some sort.

How do I get the date value out of it? I'd like a c# solution not a powershell solution such as this: https://sweeneyops.wordpress.com/2012/06/11/active-directory-timestamp-conversion-through-powershell/

Thanks

```
using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ou))
{
    using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
    {
        searcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=computer)");
        searcher.SizeLimit = int.MaxValue;
        searcher.PageSize = int.MaxValue;

        foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry computer = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

            foreach(string propName in computer.Properties.PropertyNames)
            {
                foreach(object value in computer.Properties[propName])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{propName}: {value}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know there is a long inside of the object that I can use `DateTime.FromFileTime(longType)` to get the date out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53610624/4535033): there's **no need to add a reference to a COM Types library if you need only this interface**.

To work with COM type you can define interface in your own code:

```
[ComImport, Guid("9068270b-0939-11d1-8be1-00c04fd8d503"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
internal interface IAdsLargeInteger
{
    long HighPart
    {
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity] get; [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity] set;
    }

    long LowPart
    {
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity] get; [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity] set;
    }
}
```

and use it the same way:

```
var largeInt = (IAdsLargeInteger)directoryEntry.Properties[propertyName].Value;
var datelong = (largeInt.HighPart << 32) + largeInt.LowPart;
var dateTime = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(datelong);
```

There's also a good article, explaining [how to interpret ADSI data](http://www.rlmueller.net/AccountExpires.htm)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is add a COM reference to the "Active DS Type Library"

Then the following code will make a date time out of one of the fields, for example "pwdLastSet"

```
IADsLargeInteger largeInt = (IADsLargeInteger)computer.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0];
long datelong = (((long)largeInt.HighPart) << 32) + largeInt.LowPart;
DateTime pwSet = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(datelong);
```